# Enable MOTD message on WSL and WSL2 for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, motd

I installed update-motd package on my wsl2, but how do I activate it so it shows the message every time I open a new terminal session/tab? What do I do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way to do this. I am sure there are others

Open .bashrc and add this line to the end of it

`/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo`

You will see the MOTD on every WSL2 terminal instance.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 when addding this, it only shows the technical system information that appears after the date: System load, processes, usage, users logged in, memory usage, IPv4, Swap usage. The answer by cyberconte shows the entire "Welcome to Ubuntu" info.

Answer (score 5):

add

```
 run-parts /etc/update-motd.d
```

to the end of your .bashrc

Comment: Would recommend adding `2>/dev/null` to the end of the line avoid 'permission denied' errors from spoiling the MOTD.

Answer (score -1):

Install the [WSL Utilities](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu) collection:

```
sudo apt install wslu
```

Run `wslfetch`:

[image]

Add invocation of the [wslfetch](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/wslfetch.1.html) at the end of your `~/.bashrc` script.